# Works fine on UNIX but not in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unix

So I have been working on a university project for weeks now but only on my Mac, which is running Netbeans on Lion and then everynow and then practicing using pure vi/g++/gdb on my linux installation.

I originally got the first project from my partner who put it in a .rar file. 
I extracted these and got to work, only to find later on that when I went back to Visual Studio (where I am to demonstrate this, tomorrow!), I get errors:

"Unhandled exception at 0x7736DEFE (ntdll.dll) in SDI.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00082FA4)."
Unhandled exception at 0x77373557 (ntdll.dll) in SDI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00080FEC.

It's frustrating me to the absolute maximum! My code runs perfectly in Netbeans, in terminal, and weirdly enough my friend who had the original .rar file instead zipped the files, un-zipped and then we opened his project, and removed his files, and put mine in, and it compiled perfectly! But there must be some visual studio file that saves certain settings or something because despite it running in his project, if I just copy the files into a new project it doesn't work! I'm demonstrating tomorrow and I'm really confused so any help on this subject would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: We are not psychic.  Post some code.

Comment: This probably isn't the sort of thing that will be easy to trouble shoot over the Internet. Get your friend's project that works, and next time test earlier.

Comment: Use Visual Studio to run the project in debug mode.  Hopefully it'll die in a way that makes it easy for you to figure out the problem.  You can also try running the Linux version in valgrind to see if there's a memory issue that's causing the failure in Windows.

Comment: Your towel operator is dereferencing a null babelfish on line 42 of howthehelldoyouexpectthistobeanswered.cpp

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: ohh sorry I wasn't looking for an answer in terms of how to change my code, as there is far too much to send and i wouldn't know which bits to, i meant a question in terms of why is it that visual studio won't run some things whereas my other programs will